# Generating continous reference numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sequence, auto-increment

I am designing a multi-tenant MySQL database. The way I go about is to use a single database for all the tenants, and have a tenant `ID` column in each table to separate each tenant's data.

For some of the tables, I need to generate a sequence of continuous reference numbers within a particular tenant.

For example, I have a table called `book` which contains these columns: tenant `ID` and `book` `REF`. `Book` `REF` is used to uniquely identify a `book` within a tenant. Suppose there are 2 tenants: tenant 1 and tenant 2. Each tenant has some books. Now I'd like the `book` `REF`'s in each tenant to run like 1,2,...

Obviously, `book.REF`'s in this scenario aren't really `ID`'s, since some of them in tenant 1 are identical to some in tenant 2. But since they are separated by tenant `ID`, it will just work.

I can't use 'auto_increment PRIMARY KEY' for `book` `REF`, since it will leave 'holes' in `book` `REF`'s in tenants.

So in short, there are 2 requirements for `book` `REF`:

1. they are continuous within the tenant;
2. each is unique within the tenant;

What do you think is a good way for such a goal?

Comment: imo, the way to generate sequence numbers reliably is 1) to have a table of named sequences. 2) Use transactions. 3) Explicitly lock the sequence (SELECT seq1 FOR UPDATE). 4) Update it. 5) use the sequence or throw it away. 6) end the transaction with COMMIT or ROLLBACK.. This is safe as all the accesses are serialized. I have some tested code for 'redbeanphp'.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for the suggestion. Sounds promising... Could you please share the redbeanphp link, if any? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably a trigger, even if it's not perfectly secure on heavy load.

If the same tenant insert 1M book from 10 PC, you'll probably hit a duplicate key so be sure to avoid this with `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_book ON book(id,ref)`

Anyway, here is a trigger to make the sequence for each ID tenant:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `tgi_book_ref_seq` BEFORE INSERT ON `book` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    SET NEW.ref = (
            SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ref), 0)+1
            FROM book 
            WHERE id = NEW.id
        );

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```